# MCBrowserViewController initWithBrowser usage

Tags: ios, multipeer-connectivity

I want little more control while looking for peers in MCBrowserViewController part of MultipeerConnectivity framework. Example, if no peer is found I can alert the user for the right settings to choose in the app and the peer for discovery. I tried using -[MCBrowserViewController initwithBrowser:session:] but looks like there is no way to add peers to it's UITableView as and when they are discovered. What is the intended usage of this API?

Answer (score 0):

I this case I would suggest that you create a `MCNearbyServiceBrowser` and implement your own `UIViewController` that is the browser's delegate (see `MCNearbyServiceBrowserDelegate` protocol). Then you can do custom stuff when the delegate receives calls to `browser:foundPeer:withDiscoveryInfo:` and `browser:lostPeer:`.

There's a good tutorial [here](https://www.ralfebert.de/tutorials/ios-swift-multipeer-connectivity/) that uses `MCNearbyServiceBrowser` and `MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser`.

Comment: I was doing it already but don't know why I see MCBrowserView controller as more reliable in detecting peers and connecting. MCNearbyServiceBrowser sometimes just times out and sometimes keeps on finding peers.